# Fundamentals of electron flow

Tags: current

This has been bothering me for while. I am sure there is an easy explanation behind this, but I need some insight. Current is flow of electrons, and electrons flow, when there is a potential difference.

So here I have my first question: If I connect a battery + to another battery -, why doesn't it discharge into itself, as I create a connection between high and low potential regions? I read that it is because there is no closed loop.

But then I have another question - when lightning strikes, where is the loop? It just discharges into another cloud! Also, when I walk on a carpet, get charges accumulated on my body, and then touch someone, there is a spark. Is there a loop, and if there is, where is it?

And one more: If I touch 220V line and put my foot on the ground, I die, but if there is a loop, it should have very high resistance, shouldn't it?

Comment: Guru is a good word but not needed here.

Comment: Current is flow of CHARGES. In electronics and in wires, usually electrons are the mobile charge carriers. If you connect a battery + to same battery -, you will have a closed loop, and current will flow. I am not going to try to answer for lightning. The current required to kill you is very small. This is why 220V can kill you even when the circuit has relatively high impedance. The loop is from Utility company transformer, through wires, through you, back to grounded electrode of Utility company transformer.

Comment: *If I connect a battery + to same battery -, ... is no closed loop.* Whoever told you that, wherever you read that, ignore that from now on because it is **nonsense**. Connecting the + and - of a battery creates a **short circuit loop** and the battery **will discharge** across itself (actually across it's own internal resistance). A current will flow until the chemicals needed to keep the chemical reaction going which causes current to flow, are depleted. Then the chemical reaction stops and no more current flows. The battery might get hot or even explode when you short circuit is though.

Comment: I am so sorry, I messed up! I mean another batteries -

Comment: I'm sure I've seen a duplicate of this before, but can't find it.

Comment: When you touch + and - of two different batteries together, whatever tiny transient current may flow is pretty much always insignificant. So, for all normal, everyday purposes, we say that "no current flows." Wbeaty's answer seems pretty good, and I agree with it, but I just wanted to emphasize this fact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When we connect the two batteries there's usually a current.  A brief one, then all the potentials on the battery terminals shift, and the current halts. How long does it last?

We can roughly figure it out, since it's just the "RC" equation of capacitor discharge.  The shell of a battery, plus the ground, together they act as a capacitor, and the value is perhaps around 1pF, maybe less. Or, if you're holding the battery in your hand, maybe it's higher: 10pF?  Next, the connection between batteries is a tiny fraction of an ohm.  So, when you connect the batteries, the major part of the current lasts for R*C seconds.   That's 0.01ohm * 1*10^-12farad, or a hundredth of a picosecond.  Not very long.  (The short pulse probably makes some radio waves, GHz radiation!)

Once the discharge has occurred, the potential between the connected terminals of the batteries is zero.  This means that the *other* two terminals now have ~3V between (for 1.5v zinc cells.)  Huh, so, what then did they have before touching?!  Good question.

A battery sitting on a table might be charged to a few hundred volts WRT earth.  In winter this could easily be higher: a couple thousand volts.  It's caused by handling the battery with dry fingers, or by placing the battery on an insulating surface which earlier had been brushed by clothing or skin.  The entire battery acts like a single charged object, like one capacitor-plate, with the second plate being the earth, or nearby conductors, humans, etc.  In other words (guess!) the potential between *two* separate batteries could easily be several hundred or thousand volts, with the polarity being random and unknown.  If a D-cell happens to have about +50V on it WRT earth, then one terminal might be +49.25V, the other +50.75, for 1.5V between terminals, but 50V on the battery as a whole.  Touch this to another D-cell which has, say, -632V on it, then figure out how the potentials change!

Aaaand, the same applies to dead batteries, where the voltage between each battery's terminals is zero, yet the battery may have hundreds of "floating volts" on it WRT earth.

> When lightning strikes, where is the loop?

That's just capacitor-discharge.   In thunderstorms, the regions of charged droplets become the "capacitor plates," and become conductors when the enormous streamers/fans of plasma connect them all together.  Imagine two highly-charged soup-cans sitting on a table, with a few tens of kilovolts between them.  Push them together, a spark jumps between.  Where was the loop?  Part of the loop is in space, in the collapsing e-fields found between opposite-charged cans.  Same with thunderstorms: as the e-fields collapse between the opposite-charged regions, the fast-changing fields behave like an electric current.  Search on Maxwell's equations, and look for Maxwell's great intellectual breakthrough: "displacement currents" in empty space.   When we charge/discharge capacitors, the path for current goes *through* the capacitor.  During lightning, the "loop" is completed through the capacitor dielectric, inside those collapsing e-fields located between the opposite-charge regions in the cloud.

> touch 220V line

*Usually* we're not shocked by touching live AC house-wiring.  (BUT DON'T TRY THE EXPERIMENT!)  Dry floors are going to have many megohms or even gigohms resistance to any earth connection.  If you touch a single 220V line with one finger, you'll just get some nanoamperes of capacitor-based current, where your body is one capacitor plate, and the earth is the second plate.  The danger comes from *low-resistance* connections between your body and the ground.  These are common, and famous in electrocution accidents: going barefoot on wet concrete basement floors, wearing wet shoes outdoors on wet dirt, sitting in a full bathtub, grasping a metal electrical conduit or an appliance, or leaning on grounded objects such as metal sinks.  See this [semi-complete list!](https://www.flickr.com/photos/bre/sets/72157611077138836/)

> Current is flow of electrons

Nope.  Currents *in metal wires* are flows of electrons.  That's a technician viewpoint, but the view of scientist/physicists is different.  In general, electric currents are flows of electric charges including ions and protons. For example, currents in the ground are flows of protons (called +H hydrogen ions,) plus sodium ions, chloride ions, -OH ions, and misc. other metal ions (potassium etc.)  No electrons.  When you get a shock, no electrons flow through your body, and the current is a flow of the same ions found in dirt.  Human brains and nerves aren't based on electron currents, instead they're flows of +Na, +K, and -Cl ions.

And, the currents in acids are flows of acid's primary mobile charge, the +H ion.  Proton flows!  Inside the car batteries are hundreds of amperes of proton-flow.

Comment: Great answer, thank you!

Everything is clear except for the first point. You say that the potentials are equal after short time. However, if we have 2x 1.5V batteries, one batteries + side and - side have 1.5V difference. So the same batteries + side and other batteries - side also do have 1.5V difference. How come voltage becomes equal, when you connect one batteries + to another batteries -?

Comment: Batteries are charge-pumps which actively maintain the 1.5V found between plates.  If we connect together the + and - plates of two different batteries, we've shorted two plates together, so the voltage between plates drops to zero.  During the brief pulse, each battery will fight to maintain its usual 1.5V. If you could measure both batteries during the connection, volts on *all* terminals would be changing wrt earth, but each batt always maintaining 1.5V between its own plates.  (It's like touching two charged objects together, but where each object is two plates having constant 1.5V p.d.)

Comment: +1 for mentioning displacement current (and Maxwell's Eqs) in this context: electric current requires not necessarily that charges flow; may also happen when electric field changes.

Comment: Pretty good answer! Note to anybody reading this that touching 220 V is not recommended because if there IS a conductive path through you back to the earth, for any reason, the consequences will be pretty severe. I do know someone who got shocked very badly working on AC voltage, and lost consciousness. Can't remember the full details. He is not an electrician, but was working in a place where unreasonable hazards existed, and somehow ended up getting shocked.

Answer (score 3):

According to Richard Feynman, cosmic rays bring charges into Earth's atmosphere, as rate of 7,000 amps (7,000 coulombs a second). This charge is very quick to spread around the earth. Our lightning strikes have several purposes; one is to bring this cosmic-ray energy all the way down to the surface.

Feynman discussed the puzzle: no matter where the earth is in its orbit around the sun, the peak of lightning strikes around earth always occurred at 2PM London time. There is a daily 2:1 cycle of strike occurrence.

Comment: Even though this doesn't exactly answer the question, it is kind of interesting. So I voted it back up to zero (cancelling the downvote).

Comment: Above is the broader answer to "Q: where is the loop?"   In thunderstorms, the fast-loop is a capacitor discharge.  But then the capacitor re-charges via a leakage-path through the ionosphere and back down to distant ground.   The lightning-strikes to ground produce one vertical current.  But then the opposite current (the completed loop) is located everywhere else; a slow leakage far from the storm. A tall metal tower 50KM high might "complete the loop" and intercept the other half of the current from all thunderstorms everywhere.  With no tower, the charges filter down like invisible rain.